# Why QTreeview Item class changed after drag & drop Event?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Run code below, when drag & drop an item and then click on the moved one, I expect a console message but receive an error message about :`AttributeError: 'QStandardItem' object has no attribute 'say'`

Why qt change the class of the custom Item?

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTreeView, QApplication

class DemoTreeView(QMainWindow):
    class Item(QStandardItem):
        def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            self.original_text = self.text()
        def say(self):
            print(self.original_text)

    class View(QTreeView):
        def __init__(self,parent):
            super().__init__(parent)
            self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
            self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_handle)
        def on_clicked_handle(self,index):
            item= self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
            item.say()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DemoTreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['test'])
        self.model.appendRow([self.Item("A")])
        self.model.appendRow([self.Item("B")])
        self.treeView = self.View(self)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.treeView)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DemoTreeView()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to subclass QStandardItem then you have to implement the `clone()` method and pass a custom item to the model through the `setItemPrototype()` method.

On the other hand, when an item is copied by drag-and-drop, what is done is creating an empty item and then adding the roles using QDataStream, something like:

```
# ds: QDataStream with the information of the roles of the original item
item = FooItem()
ds >> item
```

So original_text will have an empty text so a possible solution is to `say()` return the text.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTreeView, QApplication


class Item(QStandardItem):
    def say(self):
        print(self.text())

    def clone(self):
        return Item()


class View(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setDragDropMode(self.InternalMove)
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_handle)

    def on_clicked_handle(self, index):
        item = self.model().itemFromIndex(index)
        item.say()


class DemoTreeView(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DemoTreeView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUi()

    def initUi(self):
        self.model = QStandardItemModel(self)
        item = Item()
        self.model.setItemPrototype(item)
        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["test"])
        self.model.appendRow([Item("A")])
        self.model.appendRow([Item("B")])
        self.treeView = View(self)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.model)
        self.treeView.expandAll()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.treeView)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DemoTreeView()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```